# How to deal with MySQL Error: 1071 during migration from Oracle to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, oracle, migration

Our project needs to support both Oracle and MySQL. So we have a table as follows(simplified version):

```
Table name: FILE_METADATA
Columns: ID VARCHAR(36), FILE_PATH VARCHAR(2000)
```

And we have an index on this table in Oracle with both columns as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_NEXT_FILE_METADATA ON dbuser.FILE_METADATA(ID, FILE_PATH)
```

We are using the default character set for MySQL DB. I know the cause of the error is the column *FILE_PATH* which is having size *2000* but this is how it is supposed to be. How can we create such an index in MySQL so that both of our DBs(Oracle and MySQL) become the same or is there any other solution to it? as we cannot change the index in Oracle.
**PS:** Oracle version = 12c and MySQL version = 8.0.20

Comment: What character set does the FILE_PATH need to be?  Does it need to be 2000 long? If the index was less than the full size, would that still be useful?

Comment: The character set for FILE_PATH is the default. And it can be 2000 characters long as we are not sure how long the path can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1; reduce the amount of `FILE_PATH` that's in the index.

by default

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_NEXT_FILE_METADATA ON FILE_METADATA(ID, FILE_PATH)
Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes
```

This allows 768 characters. Remove 36 bytes for the `ID` and 732 is workable:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_NEXT_FILE_METADATA ON FILE_METADATA(ID, FILE_PATH(732))
```

with utf8mb4, there are 4 bytes per character

[ref fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9edea46cfa51df01909dca56978b417c)

Comment: So reducing the amount of FILE_PATH that's in the index is the only solution? or is there an option 2?

Comment: change FILE_PATH to a latin1 (8 bit) character set,  The reduced index size is hopefully enough to cover searches. It shouldn't need to go back to the primary clustered index if its less than the index length (todo - need to ensure that's true). Some really long paths may be slightly slower.